# Error with plotly subplot: Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Tags: r, plotly

I am getting an error when trying to use plotly subplot in R and I cannot figure out why. If I try to plot two plotly plots b and c:

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame("A"=1:10, "B"=11:20, "C"=21:30)

b_plot <- plot_ly(df) %>%
      add_trace(x=~A, y=~B)

c_plot <- plot_ly(df) %>%
      add_trace(x=~A, y=~C)
```

they work fine by themselves but when I try to plot them side by side in a subplot:

```
p <- subplot(b_plot, c_plot)
```

I get the error:

`Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

I can't even get the [Plotly example](https://plot.ly/r/subplots/) to work. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When running the Plotly example, what kind of error do you get? I tried to run your code and i didn't got an error

Comment: With the basic plotly example I get the same error: Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'. Interesting I think it must be something to do with the graphics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the function was being overwritten by the subplot function from the Hmisc package so changing to `plotly::subplot(...)` fixes the problem

Comment: I faced the exact issue. Thanks! Your solution helped me.